# Full disk/OS encryption solution working on UEFI/GPT-based Windows machines

Tags: windows, encryption, windows-10

Truecrypt has been discontinued (but I don't think it worked on UEFI/GPT systems anyway) and VeraCrypt [does not support UEFI/GPT](http://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/b0fb9daa/).

Do you know any (preferably opensource, but closed source is acceptable) solution? The requirements are, besides the compatibility with UEFI/GPT:

- Working with Windows 10 Home (this excludes BitLocker)
- If commercial, costing less than the upgrade to Windows 10 Pro
- No technical knowledge required from the end user in any phase, works out of the box the only effort required being to choose a password

No, this is not a duplicate of "Alternatives to TrueCrypt": I cannot find UEFI/GPT-based systems mentioned there, and TrueCrypt did not support UEFI/GPT anyway. I reckon any question regarding full disk encryption will be marked as a duplicate of that for the next 100 years. :)

Comment: [CipherShed](https://www.ciphershed.org/news/) is a TrueCrypt fork which has announced that it's working on support for UEFI bootloaders. Unfortunately that hasn't been implemented yet, and the program hasn't been updated in almost a year (which of course doesn't necessarily mean that development has stopped altogether). Perhaps it's good to keep an eye on CipherShed.

Comment: @nidunc AFAIK, the only actively supported fork of TrueCrypt it is the VeraCrypt. The good point about Veracrypt that they ran audit by third party who spotted many issues. I hope CipherShed wouldn't swamped, but as of beginning of 2017 they looks like they behind of VeraCrypt

Comment: [Note: As of version 1.18a VeraCrypt _does_ support UEFI.](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Release%20Notes)